# Groupby for each class

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Consider a table:

| Attribute1 | ... | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ... | 1 |
| B | ... | 0 |
| B | ... | 1 |
| C | ... | 0 |

I want to do a groupby of Attribute 1 for each class, something like:

| Attribute | Class 1 | Class 0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 1 |

I tried pivoting but I receive the `ValueError: Grouper for 'class' not 1-dimensional` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is:

```
  Attribute1  Class
0          A      1
1          B      0
2          B      1
3          C      0
```

Then you can do:

```
print(
    pd.pivot_table(df, index="Attribute1", columns="Class", aggfunc="size")
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .add_prefix("Class ")
)
```

Prints:

```
Class       Class 0  Class 1
Attribute1                  
A                 0        1
B                 1        1
C                 1        0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped:)